# Laravel, jquery/vue.js time difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

Welcome ! I can't find anything what will match to my code. How to do time diff with jquery or vue.js? It'll substract arrival field from departure input field and automatic show time in total time. My code for from made in laravel:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Departure time</strong>
            {!! Form::time('deptime', null, array('class' => 'form-control'     )) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>Arrival time</strong>
            {!! Form::time('arrtime', null, array('class' => 'form-   control')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <strong>Total</strong>
      {!! Form::time('totaltimeofflight',  null, array('class' => 'form-     control'))  !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com) for that. An example:

```
moment.duration(arrTime.diff(depTime)).asHours();
```

Comment: and how to use it with inputs from form? sorry Sir but i dont know java script yet .